# Uninstalling Wubi

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, uninstall, delete

I installed wubi in a 30GB partition and I wanted to delete that so that I could install Ubuntu via usb with a larger partition.

So I went to the control panel to find Ubuntu but it wasn’t there. I decided to go into the c drive and deleted the Ubuntu file. BUT now every time i boot up it asks me to choose windows 7 and Ubuntu (like I still have dual boot) and if I choose Ubuntu it says "windows could not find this file" and then says the path of the file.

what should I do to remove this old wubi/ubuntu?

Comment: The answer linked by @bcdc is the correct answer for the situation as you have described it. You can also fix the mbr by using the repair option from Windows install or recovery disks or by using EasyBCD.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ubuntu" should appear as an option under "Programs and Features" (alternatively "Add or Remove Programs").

If it doesn't, though, it is possible to use another program, EasyBCD, to remove the entry from the Windows bootloader (See this page, http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ - there is a free version for non-commmercial use at the bottom). Note: Please be careful with this as changing the wrong thing could render your OS unbootable (without some kind of recovery tools, at least)

Install and run EasyBCD, and choose "BCD Backup/Repair". Under "Backup and Restore Bootloader Settings", choose a folder to back up to and then click "Backup Settings" (this is useful in case anything goes wrong; I'd suggest doing this before making any changes from the program at all)

Then, click "Edit Boot Menu". There should be two options there (in my case, "Windows 7" and "Ubuntu"). Click the one marked Ubuntu, and then click Delete at the top. Make sure you do NOT do anything to the Windows entry; if you remove this then you will be unable to boot to Windows.

Once you restart the machine, the Ubuntu entry on your Windows bootloader should be gone.

Comment: Thanks so much you gave me the option to edit the bootloadder so i found another way to remove it from and it worked cmd since its esier to do than downloading butthanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and running [Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe).

Comment: i double click it and right click open but nothing happens even tried run as admin

Comment: i mean the program you sent

Comment: Try restoring the Ubuntu directory, then following the answer's advice.

Edited this comment after a re-read. ><;

Comment: i re downloaded wubi and then removed it from the controll panel but on the boot menu it showed 2 ubuntus and it only removed the one